# CTreeCtrl disable selection using keyboard

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Is it possible to disable the possibility of selecting items within CTreeCtrl using the keyboard to write the beginning of the word (for example looking for "Item" by pressing I or "Node" by pressing N)? How?

I'm more interested in knowing how that selection works than in actually disabling it, since it seems overriding OnKeyDown and not calling CTreeCtrl's OnKeyDown is not enough.